# Migrating a Complex PowerBuilder Application to .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

Our organization is currently facing the intricate task of migrating a substantial PowerBuilder application developed in version 2019r3 to .NET Core. This migration involves grappling with the complexities of a large codebase, incorporating PowerBuilder Foundation Classes (PFC), multilevel inheritance, data windows, nested data windows, dynamic functions, and integration with an Informix database. We are actively seeking insights, experiences, and recommendations from experts who have successfully navigated similar transitions.

Please share if you have valuable experiences or recommendations or conversion tools .

Comment: Good luck. I am currently transitioning a large PowerBuilder 1999 application to .NET  Core  and it is hell.

Comment: There are companies/people who specialize in converting PowerBuilder (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/437054/rich-bianco)